# Getting latest chrome user agent for Scrapy in python or other wise

Tags: scrapy, user-agent

Recently I have started to use Scrapy on a regular basis to analyze sites which demand the latest browser (user agent) for their content to show up.
Now, this may seem like an old time problem, yet up-to-date the issue is quite open. Why?

There is no simple API or Package to generate/download the latest version user agents (in any OS/platform).

A number of packages try to resolve this:

1. [shadow-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/shadow-useragent/) - but it relies on voluntary server which is for some reason inactive as of now.
2. [latest-user-agents](https://pypi.org/project/latest-user-agents/) - but it also uses a hosted json file + it also lists old user agents, and it doesn't have any documentation.

Lastly there is this web: [www.whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome) which is very helpful but can't be easily automated...

Any clue how to resove that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An old answer, but I was actually also looking for this feature.

Your 2nd option [latest-user-agents](https://pypi.org/project/latest-user-agents/) works as it gets the JSON file from a [daily updated](https://github.com/jnrbsn/user-agents) [source](https://jnrbsn.github.io/user-agents/) from the same author.

The reason the README.md contains old user-agents is that the repository is not updated, so this is just an example. I tried it today, and it has all the latest user-agents what I could see.